# Sidenav button-collapse disappears in materialize

Tags: materialize

I have made a sidenav and its collapse button is in the navbar using the materialize framework. The collapse-button starts disappering if the screen resolution is more than 993px. This is the code

```
 <div class="nav-wrapper">
        <ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav">
            <li><a href="#!">First Sidebar Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#!">Second Sidebar Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i></a>
        <a href="#" class="brand-logo"><img src="Logo.png" width="120"></a>
        <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right">
            <li>
                <a href="#"><img src="work/marker-5.png">Bangkok</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

My script is this

```
 $(".button-collapse").sideNav({
        menuWidth: 350,
        closeOnClick: true
    });
```

Is this due to any media query in the materialize framework?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `button-collapse` class then the menu will remain visible on wider screens.

Answer (score 0):

That it's because the materialize only use this button for phones and tablets. If you want to use it for large devise you need to add the following class to your menu item like they said in their documentation

> **Fullscreen HTML Structure**
>   If you want the menu to be accessible on all screensizes you just have to add a simple helper class show-on-large to the .button-collapse

When you do it, the code will remain in this way.

```
    <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="mdi-navigation-menu show-on-large"></i></a>
```

also i actually change the class from "mdi-navigation-menu" to "material-icons" and use the menu icon. In this case the code is going to look like this:

```
    <a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons show-on-large">menu</i></a>
```

[This is the link of the Materialize Documentation](http://materializecss.com/side-nav.html)

Hope this help you! :) In my personal opinion materializeCSS need more specific documentation for certain things.

Answer (score 0):

In you materialize.css file , change the following code,

```
 @media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
   nav a.button-collapse {
     display: none;
   }
 }
```

To

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
   nav a.button-collapse {
    display: block;
   }
 }
```

Comment: it would be nice, if you try to explain what the code does